# How to synchronize two separate Java Applications when accessing a MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, synchronization

I want to have a Java Web App and a normal Java App that both have access to the same MySQL database using JDBC. The two are of course entirely independent so what i want is to find a way to synchronize them somehow, so that i can ensure that there will be no errors to the database access due to race conditions, but i don't know how to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use transactions from your java JDBC code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactions. Pick the best isolation level of your transactions for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Most ORM solutions (hibernate, jpa) can use a 'version' column which will be checked when you attempt to write through to the database.  If the version of the object you are trying to write is different than the version in the database then you are out of date and need to merge incoming changes first.  It shouldn't be too hard to do something similar in JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions ( or some DB thing) are probably best, but if that wont work in your app, you can setup a dummy file and require write access to it as your lock.

Comment: it's a good idea but in my case can't work cause the apps are not supposed to run on the same machine!